# Azure Cosmos DB Emulator error with Azure Function

Tags: azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

I have found this error on different threads but I haven't seen a solution. I am using Azure Cosmos DB Emulator on Windows 11. And I am using an Azure Function as Trigger. It happens that when I have changed the database name parameter I get this error when I start the Function:

```
2023-12-26T17:16:04.200Z] Starting the listener for prefix='', monitoredContainer='business_docs_02', monitoredDatabase='cosmicworks_02', leaseContainer='leases_docs', leaseDatabase='cosmicworks_02', functionId='Host.Functions.MyCoFunc2' failed. Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: This builder instance has already been used to build a processor. Create a new instance to build another.
[2023-12-26T17:16:04.205Z]    at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.ChangeFeedProcessorBuilder.Build()
[2023-12-26T17:16:04.211Z]    at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.CosmosDB.CosmosDBTriggerListener`1.StartProcessorAsync() in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\WebJobs.Extensions.CosmosDB\Trigger\CosmosDBTriggerListener.cs:line 140
[2023-12-26T17:16:04.214Z]    at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.CosmosDB.CosmosDBTriggerListener`1.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\WebJobs.Extensions.CosmosDB\Trigger\CosmosDBTriggerListener.cs:line 96.
[2023-12-26T17:16:04.216Z] The listener for function 'Functions.MyCoFunc2' was unable to start.
[2023-12-26T17:16:04.217Z] The listener for function 'Functions.MyCoFunc2' was unable to start. Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Client: This builder instance has already been used to build a processor. Create a new instance to build another.
```

These are the settings of the Function's Trigger:

```
public void Run([CosmosDBTrigger(
            databaseName: "cosmicworks_02",
            containerName: "business_docs_02",
            Connection = "DBConnectionString",
            LeaseContainerName = "leases_docs",
            CreateLeaseContainerIfNotExists = true
            )] IReadOnlyList<MyDocument> input)
```

Comment: Does database `cosmicworks_02` exist in the emulator with container `leases_docs`? And if it doesn't exist what is `CreateLeaseContainerIfNotExists` set to?

Comment: Initially the cosmicworks_02 db does not exists. Then it is created, it is also created the leases container. However the container business_docs_02 is never created.

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't automatically create the collection you are trying to listen to changes on. It is expected this will already exist

Comment: Indeed this is what I have noticed. I am not sure though if this is the expected behaviour.

Comment: Entirely expected to me. The leases container is a helper container used by the function app so it makes sense that the function app can have responsibility for creating it. But it is expected that you will be writing a function to listen to changes on some container for some reason. Not just listening to changes on some randomly created empty collection just created by the app for the sake of it. You need to provision `business_docs_02` outside of this and consider partition key, throughput requirements, indexing policy

Comment: The error message certainly looks a bit cryptic and sub optimal though!

Comment: The error message means some flow in the Functions Runtime is initializing the Listener in the CosmosDBTrigger multiple times, which is unexpected. Are there any other logs that happen before the one you are attaching that might explain what is happening in the Functions Runtime?

Answer (score 0):

Can you make these [properties of the Trigger](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/issues/3455#issuecomment-1784085867) as below,

```
LeaseContainerName = "leases",
CreateLeaseContainerIfNotExists = true
```

Comment: Yes I have these settings too. I do have updated the post to make it more complete

Comment: However a way to workaround this problem is to manually create the  containerName: "business_docs_02".